# awk print column $2 and add a colon every 2 characters

Tags: printing, insert, awk

I am using awk print function to perform the following string check:

```
STRING=$(awk '{print $1" " "=" " " $2}' /tmp/test_file.out)
```

When I echo that string  it produces

```
Column1text = 090756
```

How can I insert a colon for every 2 characters in the second column?

```
Column1text = 09:07:56
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This divides the output

```
STRING=$(awk '{print $1,"=",substr($2,1,2)":"substr($2,3,2)":"substr($2,5,2)}' /tmp/test_file.out)
Column1text = 09:07:56
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()` to do this, e.g.:

```
echo Column1text 123456 | awk '{printf("%s = %s:%s:%s\n",$1,substr($2,1,2),substr($2,3,2),substr($2,5,2)) }'
Column1text = 12:34:56
```